# Send array (not array list) through UDP

Tags: java

i have array like this in client side

int arr[] = new int[]{1, 6, 3, 2, 9};

how i can send it to SERVER through UDP ? and how i can read it in SERVER side?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to an byte array, then send the byte array. The receiver converts the byte array back to an int[];

You can use the class `DataOutputStream` to create the byte array.

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
    int len = 0;
    in protokollVersion = 1;
    // Write a version, in case you want to change your format later, such that 
    // the receiver has a chance to detect which format version is used.
    dos.writeInt(protokollVersion);
    if (arr != null) {
      len = arr.length;
    }
    dos.writeInt(arr.length);
    for (int i = 0; i  < len; i++) {
        dos.writeInt(arr[i]);
    }
    dos.close();
    byte[] bytes = bos.getBytes();
```

On the receiver side, read the byte array using `DataInputStream(byte[] bytes)` and `DataInputStream.readInt()`.

Comment: can you show me how to Convert it ? because i didnt fin much help from google searching.